# Java - reflection - how to call copy constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, copy-constructor

I have this code:

**Class I want to copy:**

```
public class NormalChair extends AbstractChair {
    protected int height;
    protected String name;
    public NormalChair() {
        super();
    }

    public NormalChair(String name, int height) {
        super(name, height);
    }


    // Copy constructor - getName() and getHeight() are defined in parent class.
    public NormalChair(NormalChair chair) {
      this(chair.getName(), chair.getHeight());
    } 
}
```

**Create some class**

public Object createObj(String cls_name, String param1, int param2){
  return Class.forName(cls_name).getConstructor(String.class, Integer.class).newInstance(param1, param2);
}

Then I try to copy object of that class using this:

```
Object obj_to_copy = createObj("Classname", "name", 10);
String cls_name = obj_to_copy.getClass().getName();
Class.forName(cls_name).getConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(obj_to_copy);
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test.NormalChair.<init>(java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1708)
    at test.ProductTrader.create(ProductTrader.java:57)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

So I suppose I need to call copy constructor somehow differently than showing it's type as Object?

P.S. **Also I gave this example as simplistic. But in reality I would not know which class needs to be copied before runtime, so using copy constructor should not depend only on `NormalChair class.`**

**Update:**

I updated my question, to make it more clear that when I copy object, before, runtime, I won't know what class it will need to copy.

Comment: Maybe `Class.forName(cls_name).getConstructor(NormalChair.class)`?

Comment: Well maybe I didn't explained well. I gave simplistic example, but in reality I will not know which class I need to copy, so in constructor, I would need to use something that can change depending on class I need to copy.

Comment: Some guy posted answer that worked, but he deleted it for some reason... The thing that worked for me was to use `objc_to_copy.getClass()` inside `getConstructor`.

Comment: @Andrius, if the object that you want to copy is `nc` then `nc.getClass()` will give the `NormalChair` class

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but I can see another problem. Your AbstractChair class apparently has `height` and `name` fields, but NormalChair is declaring duplicate fields (`protected int height; protected String name;`) with the same names. Although they have the same names they are not otherwise related, and they could have different values, leading to confusion and bugs. You should remove the `height` and `name` fields on class NormalChair.

Comment: @Boann Yeah I mistakenly added them, then removed them. Anyway thanks for noticing it too.

Answer (score 0):

Java reflection for some reason matches classes and method signatures strictly. So in order to find a matching constructor, you would need to enumerate available constructors with `Class.getDeclaredConstructors()` and find a matching one.

I have written a small library to simplify the task, here is a method matching class from it: [HavingMethodSignature](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7396018).

If you're interested, here is how you [create a new instance](https://github.com/chaschev/chutils/blob/master/src/main/java/chaschev/lang/OpenBean.java#L272) with this lib:

```
Object o = OpenBean.newInstance(Class.forName(cls_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with a copy constructor in Java ? There is a standard way to copy an object in Java : simply clone it. If default cloning is not relevant, override the clone() method.

You simply need to write obj.clone() to get a copy.

see [Java documentation of clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) for details.

Comment: Will it do deep copy?

Comment: @Andrius not by default. If you need deep copy, you need to override the clone method. The best interest is that some part of you class hierarchy may need deep cloning and other not. So you only need to override when deep cloning is needed.

Comment: `clone()` on its own is bugged though because it's not public. You can't call it unless you have a reference through a more specific class or interface that overrides the method to be public.

Comment: @Boann I did not agree, it is not a "bug", it is a feature. It a design principle to not allow cloning of anything because it can have huge implications. You enable cloning (by making clone public) on what it has meaning.

Comment: @sebtic Enabling cloning is what the `Cloneable` interface is for, but that doesn't make the method public either. So, given an instanceof Cloneable, you cannot clone it.

Comment: @Boann enabling the Clonable interface is not for that. See javadoc. You can enable a superclass and a subclass while allowing only the subclass to be cloned publicly. The superclass clone method can be protected whereas the subclass clone method is public because only that has meaning. Moreover, it can be appropriate for an object to clone itself and not allow an another class to do it.

Comment: Cloneable is terribly designed and utterly broken. It's use should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that a copy constructor accepts an object of the same class, you can do something like:

```
class ObjectCopier {
    public static Object copy(Object orig) {
        Class<?> cls = orig.getClass();
        Constructor<?> con = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(cls);

        return ((con == null) ? null : con.newInstance(orig);
    }
}
```

(untested, so treat it as such)